# how to end and restore session in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, session-state

Is it possible to clear values of session on one page and restore that session on another page in asp.net c#? How? I am clearing session on **page1.aspx** then redirecting to **page2.aspx** and there session should be restored.
I have tried so far:

`Session.Abandon()`
but its not working

code on first page. `Session["searchText]` is creating problem.

```
else if (RadTabStrip1.SelectedIndex == 1)
{
    if (!Permissions.checkPermissions(Session["employeeloggedin"].ToString(), "ACCTMODF"))
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, Page.GetType(), "OnLoad", "alert('You must have the Accounts: modify permission to batch invoice!')", true);
    }
    else
    {
        // added by shiv on 07/14/2015
        Session["searchText"] = null;

        fillBatchInvoiceGrid();
```

code of second page

```
if (e.CommandName == "alpha" || e.CommandName == "NoFilter")
{

    String value = null;
    switch (e.CommandName)
    {
        case ("alpha"):
        {
            value = string.Format("{0}", e.CommandArgument);
            break;
        }
        case ("NoFilter"):
        {
            value = "%";
            Session["searchDuplicate"] = null;
            Session["searchCusSalesRep"] = null;
            break;
        }
    }
    // Session["searchletter"] = value;
    Session["searchType"] = "1";
    Session["searchText"] = value;
    Session["searchFilter"] = "1";
```

I am making `Session[searchText] = null;` on first page thats why on second page, I cant access it.

Comment: Why clearing the session when its needed on the next page. Data persistence  across pages is the essence of sessions.

Comment: its requrement. i have to clear the session because if i dont clear it. i get data which is not necessary on that perticular page.

Comment: If you really have to clear session on Page1 and get it on Page 2, I think you can (1) Store the value somewhere (server temporary data, cookie...) then access it on Page2, (2) pass the value to Page2 using query string

Comment: great. let me try this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

As per op requirement, Session[searchtext] should not be the same when it return back to the first page. Hence I'm writing the below solution to resolve the issue.

First Page:

```
Session["Searchtext"] = "something";
```

Second Page:

```
Session["Searchedtext"] = Session["Searchtext"];
Session["Searchtext"] = "";
```

**Old Answer:**

Simple in your part, Before accessing, check whether it is null or not.

```
if(Session["searchText"]!=null)
{
  //do your stuffs
}
```

Comment: i am already doing this on page1.aspx. but its issue on page2.aspx i HAVE to clear session on page1.aspx

Comment: and i HAVE to access that session on page2.aspx

Comment: @ Your question itself making confusion. I am assuming your scenario with an example. Am having Session["First"] which is holding the string name as 'Test' in first page. If i want to access this on second page,  then i can do it simple with string secondpage = Session["First"]; Here what's your question ?. You want to overwrite the same Session["first"] in second page ?

Comment: i actually want to this but i am clearing that session as per requirements so i cant access on seccond page as in your comment because i have cleared it. but still i want to restore it.

Comment: You can't do that. We can clear in two ways, one using Session["searchtext"] = ""; and other using Session.Abandon();. In both ways, you can't do this. Cos you are clearing out the values from it. And how it knows the previous value ?. You can assign the value of first page session into some other mode and clear that session. And retrieve back the values, and assign to the same Session.

Comment: so is it not possible? mo technique for that? like temporary abandon session or something like that?

Comment: As per my knowledge it's not. But still I'm not getting your exact requirement ?. I don't why they(May be your client) are asking like this ?. What is the use ?

Comment: Why you want to clear and assign back the same value in next page ?. Is this scenario, then no need of clearing it man

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83166/discussion-between-dinav-ahire-and-gkrishy).

Comment: i have comments for you in chat.

Comment: I gave some comments in chat section. Check it. @DinavAhire

Comment: @DinavAhire I updated my answer too. If it resolves your issue, make my answer as correct :). Also please let me know if you have any other issues regarding this